# How to get the html from a page opened via Javascript?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `# driver.execute_script('window.open("{}", "_blank");'.format(input_url))` instead of `driver.get` in a function which is being executed by using the `Pool` like below:

```
with Pool(2) as p:
                records = p.map(process_url, fetch_links)
```

In order to speed up the process, I am opening the URLs via Javascript by using `window.open`. It does open but did not fetch the HTML of the page. How can I tackle this? I tried `driver.get()` but parallelism is not working as it is opening URLs one by one in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem while working with javascript and html.

To open a **html file** or another website through url, you can try the following code in javascript:

```
location.replace("name.html")
```

***The html file should be in the same folder in which the js file is present.***

And try this:

```
location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

To open another website.